# MySQL - Correct Population

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables - likes, comments and posts. The likes and comments tables have IDs which refer to posts.

I want to be able to count the likes and comments on a post, however, my limited knowledge on subqueries is really proving a difficult task and no amount of research offers an answer.

I have a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dea26/2) with the layout of my tables; I've been busting my head open on my desk for hours and still not a byte closer!!

**Comments**

[image: Comment table]

**Likes**

[image: Like table]

**Posts**

[image: Posts table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` to get the required result, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.post_id, COUNT(l.like_id) AS likes, COUNT(c.comment_id) AS comments
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN likes l ON p.post_id = l.like_post
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.post_id = c.comment_post
GROUP BY p.post_id;
```

We hve used `LEFT JOIN` here which means all the records from post table would be displayed even though they don't have any like or comment.

Below is the sub query way to get the same output:

```
SELECT post_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE like_post = post_id) AS likes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments where comment_post = post_id) AS comments
FROM posts;
```

**Update**

If you want to calculate total, you can use variables in the query, e.g.:

```
SELECT post_id, 
@comments := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE like_post = post_id) AS likes,
@likes := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments where comment_post = post_id) AS comments,
(@comments + @likes) as total
FROM posts, (SELECT @comments:=0, @likes := 0) a;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use sub query to be able to add the two, like: `SELECT p.post_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE like_post = p.post_id) AS likes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments where comment_post = p.post_id) AS comments,
(likes + comments) as total
FROM posts p;` but likes and comments cannot be used in this way. Can I accomplish this?

Comment: @huzi8t9 I have updated the answer and added another query to get the total.

Comment: You're a wizard! Thank you so much. I'm so happy I could cry. I've just been moving and altering bits of SQL that I thought was right to try and get the correct code and you've nailed it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use GROUP BY for this

```
SELECT 
posts.post_id, COUNT(DISTINCT likes.like_id) as likes,COUNT(DISTINCT comments.comment_id) as comments,
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.like_post=posts.post_id
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.comment_post=posts.id
GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

You have to add DISTINCT to the COUNT as you are joining more than two tables, and you would otherwise multiply the counts of comments by the number of likes and vise versa

Comment: Thank you for your input! This is similar to what I was using initially but not the distinct count which made all the difference! Thanks :)